# Making one UIView track the animation of a single constraint on another

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, autolayout

I'm trying to learn how to animate using AutoLayout constraints.

I've got two `UIView`s, as below:

[image]

When I tap the "Up" button, I want the result to look like this. I want the red rectangle to stay the same size, but to stay pinned to the top of the gray rectangle and go along for the ride, like this:

[image]

Instead, I get this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)upButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    self.heightConstraint.constant = 20;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     } completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)downButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    self.heightConstraint.constant = 438;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     } completion:nil];

}
```

The constraint situation looks like this (screenshot--I don't know how to copy the actual list from the Document Outline). The relevant animated constraint (self.heightConstraint) is highlighted:

[image]

I confess that I find Auto Layout Constraints sort of like playing Whack-A-Mole. Can someone please help me understand how I should go about this?

Comment: You need to constrain the height of the red box to a fixed value rather than its bottom edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting constraints you need to think about how the various items relate to each other and keep in mind that the layout engine needs to be able to compute a top,left and width/height for each item.  Too many constraints can be just as problematic as insufficient constraints.

In your case you want the size of the red box to be fixed, so I would set constraints on it for width and height.  You also want its position relative to the left edge of the screen to be fixed, so set a leading space constraint to the superview.  You want its space to the grey box to be fixed, so set a trailing space constraint to the grey box.  Finally you want the top of the red box to be the same as the grey box, so select the orange box in IB, Control-drag to the grey box and select "Top" from the pop up.

For the grey box, set constraints for trailing space to the superview and bottom space to the superview (it will already have a leading space constraint to the red box).  Finally, either set a constraint for height or a constraint for top space to superview.  This is the constraint you will animate, so create an IBOutlet for it and change it in your code as required.

Comment: Excellent, Paul! Works just as you said, and thanks! I'll have to say, though, that there is a paucity of guidance as to a strategy, i.e., which constraint to set first on which object, which next, and so on. I followed your instructions step by step, and it all worked. Is it a matter of practice, or have you seen any good explicit videos or tutorials, or do I have to thrash around and beg for help every time? Thanks again, amigo!

Comment: There may be some good tutorials out there, but in my case it was a lot of frustration while I figured it out :)  As I said in my answer, over-constraining is often the biggest issue.  There can be a temptation to tick all of the boxes, which results in conflicts.  Approach your design methodically; think about what should be fixed and what should "float" and ensure that the position and size of everything can be computed

Comment: Thanks again, Paul! I'll keep practicing!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest fixing the height of the orange box. If you have a bottom constraint for the orange box remove it.

These are the constraints I would use on the orange box:
Top to the superview / Leading to the superview / Trailing to the grey box / **Height fixed** / Width fixed

These are the constraints I would use on the grey box:
Top to the superview / Leading to the orange box / **Bottom to the superview** / Width fixed

Notice the two constraints that I bolded essentially control each view's height.

I'd attach an IBOutlet to the top constraint of each view so that I could modify these values to match the behavior you want.

Comment: The orange box top should be constrained to the grey box top, not the superview and then all you need to do is animate the grey box top space constraint

Comment: Yeah you can add a constraint so that the top edges of the orange and grey views are the same, it doesn't really matter which way you do it.

Comment: Well, if you constrain the top of the orange to the top of the grey then you only need to animate one constraint, which is what the OP is after - for the top of the orange box to follow to top of the grey

Comment: Paul, it doesn't matter which way you do it. Your way involves one less IBOutlet and one less line of code. My way gives flexibility in case you decide that you want to animate the views to have different Y origins at a later point. Either way the OP has already figured out how to constrain the two views to an equal Y origin.

Comment: Also, setting both leading and trailing space constraints on the grey box plus a width constraint can lead to constraint conflicts